# possible syntax error in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

im still new to queries that call multiple tables with one call, here is my old query string,

```
$sql = "SELECT id,category,title,seo_url,product_line,look_for_terms,image,rating FROM sphinx_index WHERE id IN ($entry_ids) ORDER BY rating DESC";
```

and heres is the new one im trying to get working,

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id, a.category, a.title, a.seo_url, a.product_line, a.look_for_terms, a.image, a.rating a.status, c.username FROM sphinx_index a, entry b, users c WHERE a.id IN ($entry_ids) AND b.user_id = c.id ORDER BY a.rating DESC";
```

Comment: What's the problem?  What's happening?  What should happen?

Comment: You probably need to join `a` with either `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real question there, but if you wanna see what MySQL thinks about it: execute it and fetch the error.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === false)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Be more specific next time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird in your SQL request that table a is not joined with b or c ;
This kind of join only rarely makes sense.
Maybe you miss for example this additional clause in your WHERE :

```
AND a.id = c.id
```

but it is hard to guess what your tables are doing and what is the correct way to join a with the 2 other tables.